# Flask: Attribute Value None

Tags: python, flask

Here are my code blocks:
Below one is overriding Flask Blueprint and adding attribute **config** which copies the app's config.

```
# Overriding Flask Blueprint
from flask import Blueprint


class CustomBlueprint(Blueprint):

    def __init__(self, name, import_name):
        super().__init__(name, import_name)
        self.config = None
        self.guard = None

    def register(self, app, options, first_registration=False):
        self.config = app.config
        self.guard = app.guard
        print(self.guard) # Works Fine
        print(self.config) # Works Fine
        super(CustomBlueprint, self).register(app, options, first_registration)
```

Below one is using that class.

```
from src.SHARED.overriden.blueprint import CustomBlueprint
from .guard import module_guard

example = CustomBlueprint('EXAMPLE', __name__)
print(example.config) # Here is the problem: It prints None


@example.route('/')
@module_guard
def hello_example():
    return "Example is Working !!"
```

And I tried one another way also, using *@property, getter, and setter*. But that gives an error,
 **Attribute Error: Can't add Attribute**

I want to access/print the *app.config*, what should I do ??

Answer (score 1):

you need app.app_context().push() in your app.py

Answer (score 0):

You can access `app.config` on your Blueprints using `current_app.config`.

```py
from flask import Blueprint, current_app
from .guard import module_guard

example = Blueprint('EXAMPLE', __name__)
# Want to access current_app here e.g print(current_app.config)

@example.route('/')
@module_guard
def hello_example():
    return '{}'.format(current_app.config.get('ENV'))
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.current_app

Comment: Not Working Brother !!

Error: "Out of Context "
even after I referred docs for current_app and did that accordingly

And my intention is about to know... why it gives None ??

Comment: You can access `current_app` only when application context is pushed, for example during requests, can you post an example of what you're trying to do with the config?

Comment: yeah, i know and it works fine inside route/endpoint's function, but I want to access it outside of request function

e.g.

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app
from .guard import module_guard

example = Blueprint('EXAMPLE', __name__)
# say, I want to print app.config here for example,
print(current_app.config) # Will Throw Out of Context Her
@example.route('/')
@module_guard
def hello_example():
    return '{}'.format(current_app.config.get('ENV')) # Here, it will work fine
```